# AWS S3 CLI error when my key has blank space

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

When I run the following code in PowerShell or CMD:

`aws s3 cp s3://repositorioimagens/ampliacao/BR/1022-IKON IMAGES/STOCK239/ . --recursive`

I receive the following error:

`Unknown options .`

Because of the part `1022-IKON IMAGES` of string has a blank space, how can I especify to AWS that this part has a blank space ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `""`

```
aws s3 cp "s3://repositorioimagens/ampliacao/BR/1022-IKON IMAGES/STOCK239/" . --recursive
```

Comment: Thank you Mornor ! you help me so much.